# Выборка mysql из двух таблиц

Tags: mysql, выборка, sql

Ребят, никак не соображу, как сделать выборку из двух таблиц, может вы поможете. Вообщем нужно вывести из новости, у которой больше всего комментариев (от большего к меньшему). Первая таблица называется posts со структурой `id,date,text,raiting,sandbox`. А 2-я называется comments и имеет структуру `comment_ID, comment_post_ID, comment_author, comment_content, raiting`.

`comment_post_ID` в comments - это по сути то же самое, что и id в posts, вот как бы связать их, чтобы вывести записи из posts с наибольшим количеством комментариев вперед?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *,(select count(*) from comments where comment_post_ID = id) x 
from posts
order by x desc
```

Answer (score 2):

Я напишу оракловый запрос, т.к. MySQL на память не помню, но знаю точно, что аналогичная функциональность типа (count, DESC) там тоже есть.

Первым делом выводим из второй табл количество комментариев на каждую новость и сортируем ее

```
SELECT t.countID, t.comment_post_ID FROM (select count(comment_post_ID) as countID , comment_post_ID FROM 2_table GROUP BY comment_post_ID) t  ORFER BY t.countID DESC
```

и вторым этапом соединяем 1 таблицу с данным выводом, что есть совсем тривиально, поэтому описание опускаю...

Answer (score 1):

Решения, конечно, правильные, но осторожнее надо использовать подзапросы - это затратная операция. Для этого придумана группировка

```
select p.id,p.date,p.text,p.raiting,p.sandbox, count(*)
from posts p
left outer join comments c on c.comment_post_ID = p.id
group by p.id,p.date,p.text,p.raiting,p.sandbox
order by 6 desc
```